# Windows 7 rename files by manually dragging into place

Tags: windows-7, photos, rename, batch-rename, windows-photo-gallery

I need to manually rename a bunch of photo files so that they make more sense in sequence (I am an artist and I need to put the reference photos in the correct order so that the model appears to be rotating as I advance through them).  I need to be able to drag them around into place in sequence and then rename them so that they will maintain this order permanently.

Currently the only way I have of doing this is by moving them around on the desktop and then manually renaming them in sequence.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/npg9r.jpg

I have tried using Batch Rename Utility for this, but it was not practical because I cannot see the contents of the photos in its UI.  Is this possible in another program, Windows Live Photo Gallery, maybe?

Comment: Need a little more info. In the example you provided, were the images originally taken in that order? Or were they taken in a random order, and you're trying to set the order?

Comment: This is a perfect question for the Software Recs SE site.

Comment: As it turns out, Adobe Bridge works perfectly for this.